# Gradle sonarqube not recognizing groovy tests

Tags: gradle, groovy, sonarqube, spock

I have a multi-language project with tests implemented using Java (JUnit) and Groovy (Spock).

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

ext {
    spockVersion = '1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-3'
    groovyVersion = '2.4.7'
}

group = "at.softwarecraftsmen.poc"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit-dep:4.11"

    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$groovyVersion"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:$spockVersion"
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.8+"
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        //property 'sonar.tests', ["src/test/groovy", "src/test/java"]
        properties['sonar.tests'] += ["src/test/groovy"]
    }
}
```

When running the sonarqube task, it runs successfully but reports a `Resource not found: at.softwarecraftsmen.poc.sonar.domain.DomainTesteeSpec`. This is a Spock test using Groovy.

Here is the full log output from produced by Gradle:

```
$ ./gradlew clean jacoco sonarqube 
:clean
:compileJava
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
objc[4573]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
:jacocoTestReport
:sonarqube
Resource not found: at.softwarecraftsmen.poc.sonar.domain.DomainTesteeSpec
CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 941ms
Resource not found: at.softwarecraftsmen.poc.sonar.domain.DomainTesteeUnitTest
File not found: at/softwarecraftsmen/poc/sonar/domain/DomainTestee.java
Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
File not found: at/softwarecraftsmen/poc/sonar/domain/DomainTestee.java
Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Adding `properties['sonar.tests'] += ["src/test/groovy"]` does not fix the problem, only tests from `src/test/java` are reported properly.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-01-03 15:31:04 UTC
Revision:     075893a3d0798c0c1f322899b41ceca82e4e134b

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_71 (Oracle Corporation 25.71-b15)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886878/integrate-spocks-test-with-sonar

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed the Groovy plugin in Sonar as explained here:

[Integrate Spock's test with Sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886878/integrate-spocks-test-with-sonar)

You need admin access on your Sonar instance to do this.

Comment: I have the same issue. After adding the plugin as mentioned in the linked question I see the tests appearing in SonarQube. However, coverage data does not consider the Spock tests.