# Integrate Spock's test with Sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, spock

I use spock to write test case and jenkins to run and publish my test cases.
I was able to get the code coverage reported but sonar shows me **only Java** Unit test cases; the **groovy test cases are totally missing**

The following pom.xml is used as reference
https://github.com/kkapelon/java-testing-with-spock/blob/master/chapter7/spring-standalone-swing/pom.xml

would anyone please know what I am  missing ?

[image: Sonar Dashboard image]

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452851/gradle-sonarqube-not-recognizing-groovy-tests

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Install the Groovy plugin in Sonar. Login as admin/admin and go to
   the administration/system/update-center tab
2. Add the following property in the
   pom file

   <sonar.tests>src/test/groovy,src/test/java</sonar.tests>

If you do this both Spock and JUnit tests are shown correctly! 
See attached screenshot 
[image: Spock and JUnit tests in Sonar]